# Why the widgets I have inside the GenerateQR class doesn't show up?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, tkinter

I'm converting my code to OOP, and I fixed all the errors so far from this code snippet, but I couldn't figure out why widgets in the GenerateQR class doesn't show up, even tho the class is called and I can use print() inside it, here is the code I converted so far and got stuck in:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox, scrolledtext
import ttkbootstrap as ttk
from ttkbootstrap.constants import *
from tkinterdnd2 import *
import qrcode
import cv2
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import ctypes

class MyApp(ttk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("QR Code Generator")

        # self dimensions
        self_height = 660
        self_width = 700
        screen_width = self.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = self.winfo_screenheight()
        x_cordinate = int((screen_width/2) - (self_width/2))
        y_cordinate = int((screen_height/2) - (self_height/2))
        self.geometry(f"{self_width}x{self_height}+{x_cordinate}+{y_cordinate}")

        # self window icon
        self.iconbitmap("assets/qr_icon.ico")

        # Creating tabs and frames
        self.tabs = ttk.Notebook(self, bootstyle="light")
        self.tabs.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH, pady=5, padx=5)

        self.generate_tab = ttk.Frame(self.tabs)
        self.tabs.add(self.generate_tab, text="Generate QR")
        
        GenerateQR(self.generate_tab)

class blank_qr():
    def __init__(self, parent):
        photo_0 = Image.open("assets/blank_qr_code.png")
        max_size = (300, 300)
        photo_0.thumbnail(max_size)
        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(photo_0)

class GenerateQR(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        # Creating Widgets
        data_label = ttk.Label(self, text="Enter your text :")
        data_label.pack(pady=5)

        self.text = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(
            self,
            wrap="word",
            height=4,
            font=('Calibri', 10)
        )
        self.text.pack(fill="x", padx=10)
        self.text.focus()

        self.text.bind("<Button-3>", self.show_context_menu)

        buttons_frame = ttk.Frame(self, width=60)
        buttons_frame.pack(pady=15)

        generate_button = ttk.Button(buttons_frame,
                                     text="Generate QR Code",
                                     bootstyle="dark-outline",
                                     command=self.generate_qr_code
                                     )
        generate_button.pack(side="left", padx=10)
        generate_button.bind("<Button-1>", self.generate_qr_code)
        self.bind("<Return>", self.generate_qr_code)

        reset_button = ttk.Button(buttons_frame,
                                  text="Reset",
                                  bootstyle="dark-outline",
                                  command=self.reset_qr_code
                                  )
        reset_button.pack(side="left", padx=5)

        save_button = ttk.Button(buttons_frame,
                                 text="Save QR Code",
                                 bootstyle="dark-outline",
                                 command=self.save_qr_code
                                 )
        save_button.pack(side="left", padx=10)

        qr_code_frame = ttk.Frame(self)
        qr_code_frame.pack()

        self.qr_code_label = ttk.Label(qr_code_frame, image=blank_qr(self).photo)
        self.qr_code_label.pack()

        self.status_label = ttk.Label(self, text="", font=("Calibri", 12))
        self.status_label.pack()

    def generate_qr_code(self, event=None):
        data = self.text.get('1.0', 'end')
        if not data:
            return

        qr = qrcode.QRCode(
            version=1,
            error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
            box_size=10,
            border=4,
        )
        qr.add_data(data)
        qr.make(fit=True)

        img = qr.make_image(fill_color="black", back_color="white")

        qr_width, qr_height = img.size
        max_width = 300
        max_height = 300

        if qr_width > max_width or qr_height > max_height:
            ratio = min(max_width / qr_width, max_height / qr_height)
            new_width = int(qr_width * ratio)
            new_height = int(qr_height * ratio)
            img = img.resize((new_width, new_height))

        qr_code_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        self.qr_code_label.config(image=qr_code_img)
        self.qr_code_label.image = qr_code_img

        self.status_label.config(text="Done ✔", bootstyle="success")

    def reset_qr_code(self):
        self.text.delete('1.0', 'end')
        self.qr_code_label.config(image=self.photo)
        self.qr_code_label.image = None
        self.status_label.config(text="")

    def save_qr_code(self):
        qr_code_img = self.qr_code_label.image
        if qr_code_img:
            path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".png",
                                                filetypes=[("PNG files", "*.png")])
            if path:
                qr_code_img = qr_code_img._PhotoImage__photo  # Get the internal PhotoImage object
                qr_code_img.write(path)
                messagebox.showinfo("Info", "Saved")

    def paste_text(self):
        copied_text = self.clipboard_get()
        self.text.insert("insert", copied_text)

    def show_context_menu(self, event):
        context_menu = ttk.Menu(self.text, tearoff=0)
        context_menu.add_command(label="Paste", command=self.paste_text)
        context_menu.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MyApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

- I tried to remove the blank_qr code
- I tried to tweak  the `__init__` method and the `super()__init`

Nothing worked for me, please help.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work, but you are not calling self.generate_tab.pack(), so all content inside that frame will not be visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GenerateQR(self.generate_tab)` creates a frame widget but you still need to use a geometry manager (pack, grid, place) for it to show up.

Use something like

```
self.generate_qr = GenerateQR(self.generate_tab)
self.generate_qr.pack()
```

Comment: Yes it works, I tried pack() in different ways before, but this works now, thank you so much bro, much appreciated